# Why putting a DispatchQueue delay function inside another DispatchQueue has no effect in Swift

Tags: loops, swift3, xcode8, delay, delayed-execution

Expected Behavior:

For i = 0, print statement called after 0  second .

For i = 1, print statement called after 1.1 seconds

For i = 2, print statement called after 2.2 seconds

Actual Behavior:

Print statement called after 0, 1, 2, 3 seconds respectively i.e. inner delay function is ignored.

So why the discrepancy?

```
    for i in 0...3 {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(i), execute: {  

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(i/10), execute: {
                print("function was called")
            })      
        })
    }
```

Comment: But what's the _question_? What is it that you are hoping to _do_?

Comment: To make it execute the print statement every 1 second after another

Comment: Well, your code isn't going to do that; the `for in 0...5` executes all the loops _immediately_.

Comment: But this has been answered hundreds of times. Personally, I would use `delay` and recurse instead of looping. But in addition, what you are asking to do is totally artificial; no one would ever do it in real life. You would do better to ask about the _real_ problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this.  Here are 3:

**Use a timer to repeat a block every second**

```
var i = 0
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
    i += 1
    print("hello \(i)")
    if i == 5 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

**Dispatch multiple async tasks**

```
for i in 1...5 {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(i)) {
        print("hello \(i)")
    }
}
```

Note:  This queues all of the tasks up front and could overflow a queue if there were a large number of them.

**Run loop in background with sleep and switch to foreground to print**

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    for i in 1...5 {
        sleep(1)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("hello \(i)")
        }
    }
}
```

Note:  This will drift a little (not be 1 second apart) if the work in the loop takes a significant amount of time.

Comment: does `DispatchQueue.global()` has default sleep ? I think it self has 1 second sleep. am I right?

Comment: @MHSFisher, there is no built-in 1 second sleep that I'm aware of.  The way I wrote it, the sleep is before the first print, so there will be a 1 second delay before the first print appears.  You could move the sleep to after `DispatchQueue.main.async` for a quicker start to the output.

Comment: i'm reading from socket server in `DispatchQueue` in an infinite loop but the speed of each loop is like sleeping 1 second. do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @MHSFisher, I do not.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly valid to embed a call to DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter() inside another call.  The simple reason the original code does not seem to be working is that the second call has a deadline of .now() + .seconds(i/10), where i is an Int, and 0/10 == 0, 1/10 == 0, etc. (until i reaches 10).

Changing the code to deadline: .now() + .seconds((Double(i) / 10.0) will fix it.

Comment: Why bother criticizing the other answers?

Comment: Sorry.  Didn't realize that pointing out that other answers are wrong (or just not answering the original question) is considered to be criticism. I'll try to keep the editorial comments out in the future.